# How to save photo after clicking in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

Here's my button to initiate the camera:

```
-(IBAction)TakePhoto{


    // check if camera exists...to test on simulator
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])  {


        picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate =self;
        [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }
    else
    {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"" message: @"Camera not available on this device" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]; [alert show];

    }



}
```

I just want it to save it to the photo library and then come back to the view controller.

Got it working like this: Added these 2 delegates, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo and

imagePickerControllerDidCancel.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{


    image= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    [imageView setImage:image];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];



}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Where's your code for the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` methods?

Comment: Thanks for helping guys. Can you please stop down-voting now? I've posted the correct answer too and I'm still being down-voted so I can't ask any more question now.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```